# Multiple Many-to-many relationships in JPA/Hibernate Eager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I would like to get some advice with a question that might make no-sense or may be it does. Let's have a profile object that has a set of Interest with a Many2Many relationship like this one:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="profile_interests", 
joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="profile_id") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="interest_id") } )
@OrderColumn(name="display_order")
private Set<Interest> interests;

//GETTER AND SETTERS
public Set<Interest> getInterests() {
    return interests;
}
public void setInterests(Set<Interest> interests) {
    this.interests = interests;
}
public void addInterest(Interest interest) {
    interests.add(interest);
}
public void removeInterest(String interestName) {
    interests.remove(new Interest(interestName));
}
```

In my application controller I can add and delete interests in this way.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save-interest", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> saveInterest(@RequestParam("name") String interestName) {

    SiteUser user = getUser();
    Profile profile = profileService.getUserProfile(user);

    String cleanedInterestName = htmlPolicy.sanitize(interestName);

    Interest interest = interestService.createIfNotExists(cleanedInterestName);

    profile.addInterest(interest);
    profileService.save(profile);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}


@RequestMapping(value="/delete-interest", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteInterest(@RequestParam("name") String interestName) {

    SiteUser user = getUser();
    Profile profile = profileService.getUserProfile(user);

    profile.removeInterest(interestName);

    profileService.save(profile);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Eventually, a profile, a profile_interests and an interests table will be created. The profile_interest table will have a profile_id and an interest_id, right?

**Now imagine that I also want to have other Sets of let's say: activities, passions OR hates, dislikes, tasks, vocations. I can repeat these same process again and again to cover the 6 new (activities, passions, hates, dislikes, task, vocation).**

At some point one person may have and interest in Cars, whether other has a passion in Cars, a third one hates Cars and a fourth one say Cars are his Vocation.

If I create 7 different Sets of objects (interests, activities, passions, hates, dislikes, task, vocation) I will repeat many of them in all the tables.

**-Is there any way to have a common (interests, activities, passions, hates, dislikes, task, vocation) table for the 7 set of objects, but 7 different intermediate tables (profile_interests, profile_activities, profile_passions, profile_hates, profile_dislikes, profile_task, profile_vocation) using the common table?**

Thanks. I appreciate your help with a non-programmer. May be it is a problem well documented and already solved, I dont know.

PD: The Interest entity is here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interests")
public class Interest implements Comparable<Interest> {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "interest_name", unique = true, length = 25)
private String name;

public Interest() {
}
```

Comment: setting `fetchType` as `EAGER` is not good for `Many2Many` relation, specially you have multiple of that.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I will remenber your advice if I use it multiple times, but that is what I'm trying to avoid (use it many times). Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: It is possible, but not as straight-forward as you want: you will need to map 7 objects, one for each: profile_interests, profile_activities, profile_passions, profile_hates, profile_dislikes, profile_task, profile_vocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPA 2 entities can be related in more than one ways - and it is perfectly legal. So, just like the interests, the (say) activities would be mapped in the `Profile` entity as:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) // don't use EAGER unless you really want to :)
@JoinTable(name="profile_activities",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="profile_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="interest_id") } )
@OrderColumn(name="display_order")
private Set<Interest> activities;

//GETTER AND SETTERS AS FOR interests
```

You haven't shown the `Interest` entity. *If* the relations are bidirectional, the `Interest` would have to have many different `Set<Profile>` fields, one for each relation it participates (interests, activities, ...). In that case the `mappedBy` attribute of the field in the `Interest` entity must point to the appropriate field of the `Profile`.

This also assumes that business-wise all the relations are between the same entities. A side-effect would be that the list where the user must pick an activity is the same as the list where the user must pick an "interest". If that it not exactly so, then you may have to do more.